# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am getting the exception (*unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll*) when I tried to query large data using linq. The code which is throwing the error is,

```
    if (codeList != null && codeList.Count > 0)
        {
            List<string> codes = codeList.Select(x => x.DeptCode).Distinct().ToList();

            nameList = db.LegacyCodeDetails.Where(x => x.LegacyIdentifier.Contains(identifier) &&
                                                           x.ColumnAbr != null && x.ColumnAbr.Equals("NAME") &&
                                                           (codes.Where(y => x.LegacyIdentifier.Contains(y)).Count() > 0)
                                                    )
                                               .Select(x => new NameAndValue { Name = x.Value, Value = x.LegacyIdentifier }).Distinct().ToList();

            List<string> namesToDisplay = nameList.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

The same code works fine when there is hundreds of records. I am wondering what could be the issue.

Inner Exception: Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

**Environment:**

Visual studio 2012, Entity Framework 6.0, C#, SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Question:**

Am I doing anything wrong with the linq which is causing this exception? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which line is it throwing an exception on? There are many ToList()s in the above example where it could occur.

Comment: Stackoverflow-- well yeah you are getting lots of data into memory. Can you do it without ToList. ToList brings the whole data into memory and does filtering in the memory( linq to object)....but if you just have one query and do the to list only once. It might improve it

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is occurring because `codes` is too large and you are mixing an IQueryable (`db.LegacyCodeDetails.Where`) with an IEnumerable (`codes`) so the generated SQL will contain a line for every item in `codes`.

If `codes` comes from another table you could directly access that table in the query. For example:

Replace:

```
codes.Where(y => x.LegacyIdentifier.Contains(y)).Count() > 0)
```

with:

```
db.Codes.Select(y => y.DeptCode).
        .Where(y => x.LegacyIdentifier.Contains(y)).Any())
```